# BCP Utility. Creating format-file

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

MSDN says that if table name is `myTestFormatFiles`, table is created in the `AdventureWorks2012` sample database under the `dbo` schema, so the command is:

```
bcp AdventureWorks2012..MyTestFormatFiles format nul -c -t, -f myTestFormatFiles.Fmt -T
```

My case:

[image]

I tryed this one:

```
bcp TestDB..test_table format nul -c -t, -f d:\format.fmt -T
```

Here is the result:

```
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 2
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Named Pipes Provider: Could no
t open a connection to SQL Server [2].
SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 2
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-
specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Serve
r is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL S
erver is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Se
rver Books Online.
SQLState = S1T00, NativeError = 0
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired
```

I think something wrong with `TestDB..test_table`. May be I need to specify `k551l\sqlexpress` in command, something like `k551l\sqlexpress..TestDB..test_table`.

What is my problem really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the server\instance names with by adding `-S k551l\sqlexpress` to your command.